# AWS Lambda /tmp files - Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c++, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am downloading a set of CSV files from S3 to Lambda's 'tmp' folder. I then feed the files as input to a C++ executable file which I packaged in my Lambda zip deployment.

**Lambda: main.js**

```
exports.handler = function(event) {        
process.env['PATH'] = process.env['PATH'] + ':' + process.env['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT']

var bucket = 'test',
    fileKey = 'processed/2019-06-25/',
    fileNames = ["a.csv", "b.csv", "c.csv"];

    try {
        s3.download(bucket, fileKey, fileNames)
        console.log("tmp after s3 download");
        let files = fs.readdirSync('/tmp/');  
        files.forEach(function (file) {
            console.log(file); 
        }); 

        let result = proc.execSync('./run', {stdio: 'inherit'});
    }
catch(e){
    console.log(e);
    return e;
}        
}
```

**S3 Download Util**

```
downloadFromS3 = function (bucket, fileKey, fileNames) {
        'use strict';
        console.log('downloading', bucket, fileKey, fileNames);
            for (var i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) {
                var filePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileNames[i]),
                file = fs.createWriteStream(filePath),
                stream = s3.getObject({
                    Bucket: bucket,
                    Key: fileKey +  fileNames[i]
                }).createReadStream();
                stream.pipe(file);
            }
    }

module.exports = {
    download: downloadFromS3
};
```

**Here is my run file** (calc.exe is part of lambda zip)

```
./calc -d /tmp/
```

The above command throws segmentation error, but if I create a directory say 'data' with the same csv files (instead of downloading from s3 to /tmp), check it in with Lambda code and use, it works without any error, so below command will work.

```
./calc -d ./data
```

I did verify all the required csv files are downloaded to **/tmp**, but it keeps throwing segmentation error if I use **/tmp**. However **./data** works fine.

Comment: It's just a wild guess, but does the machine you run your code on use tmpfs for `/tmp`?  It's a fast but limited size memory-only file storage (think ramdisk), maybe you just filled it up completely and your code can't handle such a situation?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs

Comment: size of tmp in AWS lambda is 500mb, the size of all my files combined is less than 10mb.